# Discord бот, взаимодействия API

Tags: python, discord.py, discord-api

только начал кодить, очень заинтересовала эта тема со «взаимодействиями» в чате серверов.

не понимаю как сделать упоминание при отправке ботом сообщения.

также очень хотел бы узнать, как добавлять собственный архив gif (на сайте GIPHY), откуда и можно брать подобное.

Прикреплю скриншот действия, которое хотел бы понять. Всем заранее спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: <@{айди}> - создать упоминание

Comment: получить id упоминаемого пользователя из сообщения - message.mentions[0].id

Comment: вы разобрались как это делать?

Answer (score 0):

Давайте зайдем в документацию по библиотеке `discord-py`, в раздел [**`discord.User`**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=user#discord.User).

В списке **Attributes** видим атрибут `mention` (*упоминание*), который можем применить к объекту пользователя.

Чтобы получить объект пользователя, сразу зададим тип объекта аргумента при создании функции:

```
@bot.command()
async def mention(ctx, user: discord.User):
    # действия при вызове команды
```

Таким образом, при получении аргумента `user`, он сразу же будет преобразован из типа `str` к типу `discord.User`.

Далее, можем упомянуть его в сообщении через атрибут:

```
await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} упомянул пользователя {user.mention}')
```

---

**Полный код:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = discord.Intents.all())

@bot.command()
async def mention(ctx, user: discord.User):
    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} упомянул пользователя {user.mention}')

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

**Не забудьте указать ваш токен в конце!**